# C# is there a difference between where() and where<T>()

Tags: c#, linq, generics

In C# linq, is there a difference between `A.where(...)` and `A.where<SomeClass>(...)` where `A` is some type of suitable collection?

Comment: No; generic type inference

Comment: There is no .Where(), if you type that you are actually using .Where<T>() where the T is inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general no, because the compiler will infer the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<>` `A` and use as the generic parameter of the `.Where<>()`

**but**

You could force the `Where<>` to "use" a `SomeClass` that is a base class of the `T` type of the `IEnumerable<>` (this works because `IEnumerable<>` is covariant, so `IEnumerable<subclass>` can be "casted" to `IEnumerable<baseclass>`)...

The only practical result would be that you would "see" in the `Where()` a little "less" of `T` (and that if there are properties/methods of `T` that are "overwritten" by `SomeClass` you will access them without having to do casts)

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class MySubClass : MyClass
{
    // Note the use of *new*. This isn't a virtual method!
    public new int GetNumber()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

MySubClass[] coll = new[] { new MySubClass(), new MySubClass() };
var res = coll.Where(x => x.GetNumber() == 2).ToArray(); // 2 elements
var res2 = coll.Where<MyClass>(x => x.GetNumber() == 2).ToArray(); // 0 elements
var res3 = coll.Where<MyClass>(x => x.GetNumber() == 1).ToArray(); // 2 elements
```

Comment: You might want to mention that "SomeClass override is called instead of the base class"-part is just a general OOP "feature", and that it's not reliant on the Where method. Still a valid point though

Comment: I think you got it the wrong way. With your names, `T` can be a subclass of (and must not be a value type) `SomeClass`. The reason why it works, is (of course) that `IEnumerable<>` is a covariant generic type. So if `T` is a reference type which derives from `SomeClass`, then any `IEnumerable<T>` "is" an `IEnumerablce<SomeClass>`. So it is legal to set the [`TSource` type argument of the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) equal to `SomeClass`. This cannot usually be inferred, so the type argument is written explicitly.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, with T I was thinking of the `IEnumerable<T>`, not the T of the `Where<>`

Comment: OK, so the covariance goes `collectionMySubClass.Where<MyClass>(...)`. It is not possible to go the other way implicitly. If you tried `collectionMyClass.Where<MySubClass>(...)`, it would fail. That way would need an explicit cast, as in `((IEnumerable<MySubClass>)collectionMyClass).Where(...)`. And it may well fail at run-time, depending on the actual run-time type of the array, `List<>` or other source.